# Advanced definition of derivative.

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

In the paper *[On proof and progress in mathematics](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9404236v1.pdf)*, W. P. Thurston gives the following interpretation of the derivative.

> ...one
>   person’s clear mental image is another person’s intimidation:
>
> The derivative of a real-valued function $f$ in a domain $D$ is the Lagrangian section of the cotangent bundle $T^∗(D)$ that gives the connection form for the unique flat connection on the trivial $\mathbf R$-bundle $D\times \mathbf R$ for which the graph of $f$ is parallel.

In order to make this interpretation clear, what should a person who only finished a "traditional" Calculus course (say in the James Stewart's style) read?

Indications of books or chapter of books would be great.

Comment: To me a derivative is the function without memory :p

Comment: You would need to know what a connection is and what a Lagrangian submanifold is. For the first, read any book on differential geometry that talks about connections. I like Taubes (but that assumes a first manifolds course, eg Lee). Then you want to read the beginning of a symplectic manifolds book. Keep in mind that this definition is mostly a joke; I would be astonished if there was a mathematician who actually found this an inspiring definition of the derivative. See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/449740/98602).